# Importing Frame animation into Cocos2d-js v3.3 from Cocos Studio 2

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

Cocos2d-js v3.3 was just released, and it is promised that we can now export frame animations from Cocos Studio 2 as a JSON (not a csb) and use them in this latest version of cocos2d-js.

I have been looking for instructions on how to do this for most of the day, without success. Does anyone know of a good example, tutorial, or guide that explains this?

Please note, I am only interested in Cocos2d-js, not Cocos2d-x

Comment: I am no longer following this thread. If you find the answer, please start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use armature as sprite.

documentation below :
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V2.2.1/symbols/ccs.Armature.html

Comment: This link does not go to an "example, tutorial, or guide," as was requested. It goes to documentation, without specifying the context in which I can use the documentation to achieve my ends. 

Additionally, this is documentation for skeletal animation, not frame animation. I believe they are different concepts.

I usually wouldn't criticize anyone for attempting an answer, but it looks like you put about 30 seconds of Googling into this answer and only half read my question.